# Mongodb data disappearing

Tags: mongodb

I have a really weird issue.

I'm inserting data into my mongodb (with meteor), so If I query the database I can see it and all's good.

If I query it in MongoVue or MongoHUB I can see all the data there (I create it in quite a few collections)

But shortly after (only sometimes randomly) it all just disappears. It had already been committed to the data base and then it sort of goes undone as if I had never inserted the first few sets. I've not run any `remove` or `update` commands.

What could be causing this weird behaviour?

Update: This one time round the data returned, on previous occasions it doesn't return. Could it be something to do with the journal?

Comment: Have you looked at the MongoDB log?  This should not have anything to do with the journal.  What Meteor functions are talking to MongoDB?

Comment: Actually I was running it with meteor so there wasn't a log. It was all really strange that It came back because I made a query to mongodb directly and it wasn't there, then I restarted it and suddenly its back! So I used a fresh database and hopefully that doesn't happen again

Comment: Have you been using safe writes with MongoDB?

Comment: I have two sections that were making writes, one was an express app, which were safe & the other bit was with meteor, i'm not too sure whether they are safe. If both are used together does it cause problems?

Comment: It shouldn't - are you using a standalone mongod or a replica set?

Comment: After a bit of investigation I've found its to do with keeping the connection open for long, and if the app closes before calling db.close() from a crash this weird data disappearing episode occurs sometimes. I was using the same db connection for many collections throughout the app, so one connection per app instance then running .close before closing the app down.